# How to make multiline progress indicator in terminal

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a progress display in terminal,
This is what i done

```
import time
dots = ['', '.', '..', '...']
for i in range(11):
    print(f'\rtime: {i} sec\t\tEstimated time: 10 sec', end='', flush=True)
    if(i != 10):
        print(f'\rStatus: copying{dots[i%4]}', end='', flush=True)
    else:
        print(f'\rStatus: done!!!')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want something like this,
[image]

But this my current output looks like,
[image]

How to make it in two lines and update only the time and status string

if i try like this,

```
import time
dots = ['', '.', '..', '...']
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(f'\rtime: {i} sec\t\tEstimated time: 10 sec', flush=True)
    if(i != 10):
        print(f'\rStatus: copying{dots[i%4]}', flush=True)
    else:
        print(f'\rStatus: done!!!')
    time.sleep(1)
```

the ouput looks like this, 
[image]

Comment: Will [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) do the trick for you?

Comment: @Schottky yeah, but how to do that without using any external library that's what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Yea but why no external libs?

Comment: @XxJames07- I'm not trying to build any useful thing out of it i doing this to learn about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the two lines is that it goes beyond the capabilities of what `\r` can do for you. Probably the only way you can do what you want is using ANSII escape characters. Here it is spelled out:

```py
for i in range(11):
    print(f'time: {i} sec\t\tEstimated time: 10 sec')
    if i != 10:
        print(f'Status: copying{("." * (i % 4)).ljust(3)}')
        print('\033[3F')
    else:
        print('\033[2F')
        print(f'\nStatus: done!!!    ')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Let's go over it:
The `\033` character is the octal value for the ASCII escape character. The next character (`[`) indicates that the next command is from the CSI group of commands. CSI stands for Control Sequence Introducer and sets the scene for the next command. The number is the number of rows to go up and the `F` character means 'move `n` lines up'.

Note that this only works in a terminal that allows these escape chars. This is true for most terminals, however, it *might* just not be true for a debug terminal in your IDE (if you are using one).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want external libraries, as @Schottky suggested would be to use [`ANSII`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) escape character, *but* this wouldn't work on OSs like `Windows` cmd (probably OP's), to enable that you would use `ctypes`,
you can eneble that by simply doing:

```
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
```

and then, improvin:

```
secs=11
for i in range(secs):
    print(f'time: {i} sec\t\tEstimated time: {secs-i} sec')
    print(f'Status: copying{("." * (i % 4)).ljust(3)}')
    print('\033[3F')
    sleep(1)
print('\033[2F')
print('Status: done!!!')
```

but if you want to do it with external libs,
you should see [`tqdm`](https://tqdm.github.io/):

it can be installed with

```
> $ pip install tqdm
```

Code:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
for x in tqdm(range(11),"Copying",11):
    sleep(1)
else:
    print("Done!")
```

out:

```
Copying: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 11/11 [00:11<00:00,  1.01s/it]
Done!
```

Comment: How to do this without using the **tqdm**

Comment: Oh no no,  it's i'm just curious about how to get it done without using any external library. I heard about the **tqdm** before i'm trying to learn about how to do that with only built in modules.

Comment: ok, i will provide a solution rn

Comment: @ABHIJITHEA could you see the solution provided?

Comment: No this not what i am looking, my problem is i can't keeping it in two seperate lines that is looks like this,                                                                                         time: 5 sec    Estimated time: 10 sec                                                                        Status: copying...                                                                                                       and update the the number at "time: " and "Status: "

Comment: i've updated my question, I hope it show what kind of output i'm looking

Comment: updated the answer, hope it fills the blank in the question of Schottky

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242627/discussion-between-xxjames07-and-abhijith-ea).